# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , pass multiple variables to javascript function

Tags: javascript

I want to add button to div of "abc". When the button is pressed, it will pass multiple variables to javascript function.

```
document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML = 
"<button type='button' class='button3' onclick='delete_post(" +   
para1 + "," + para2 +")'>delete</button>";
```

The error of Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , appears. 
I pass multiple variables to javascript function like

```
"<button ... onclick='delete_post(" + para1 + "," + para2 +")' ... >";
```

How can I pass multiple variables to javascript function?

---

Solution:

```
"<button ... onclick='delete_post(\"" + para1 + "\",\"" + para2 +"\")' ... >";
```

Quote the js variables with \" around them.

Comment: what are para1 and para2 ?

Comment: They are js variables.

Comment: what are the values inside it?

Comment: para1 is file path eg. abc/12345.jpg and para2 is time eg. 2016-02-28 16:50:00

Comment: Those are strings, you are not properly quoting them

Comment: Yes, you are right. So, If I pass the js variables storing strings, I need to quote them properly.

Comment: Properly, I should write the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `para1` and `para2` are strings you have to wrap it inside quotes before passing those as parameters,

```
".. onclick='delete_post(\"" + para1 + "\",\"" + para2 +"\")'>delete</button>";
```

Comment: I don't know \" para1 ' that works or not. However,  If I pass the js variables storing strings, I need to quote them properly. I usually surround those string variables with \"

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works for me.

```
var btn = document.createElement("button");
btn.addEventListener("click",delete_post(para1,para2));
btn.className="button3";
document.getElementById("abc").appendChild(btn);
```